# Probability of rolling identical numbers with polyhedral dice.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, dice

Is there a way to calculate the number of identical rolls in polyhedral dice rolls?

A specific example: I roll $3$ times a $12$-sided dice.

What are the odds of rolling some number twice with 3 dice? E.g. $(4,4,7)$ , $(4,2,4)$...

AND: What are the odds of rolling some number $3$ times with $3$ dice? E.g. $(4,4,4)$, $(11,11,11)$...

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to calculate the probability of this when rolling 2 dice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rolling three $n$-sided dice and getting **exactly** one pair of dice which match (*counting results like (4,2,4) but not counting results like (6,6,6)*) we count how many possible triples of numbers have this property via multiplication principle.

- Pick the number used for the pair
- Pick the number used for the singleton
- Pick the location in the triple used by the singleton

There are $n$ choices for the number used for the pair.  Given that selection, there are $n-1$ remaining choices to use for the singleton.  Regardless of these choices, there are $3$ positions available for the singleton to be placed in in our triple.  Applying multiplication principle, there are then $3n(n-1)=3n^2-3n$.

In the case of a $d6$ that would be $6\cdot 5\cdot 3 = 90$ possibilities.

If we were to include also the results where all three dice show the same result, that would be an additional $n$ possibilities, bringing the new total to $3n(n-1)+n=3n^2-2n$, in the case of a $d6$ a total of $90+6=96$ possibilities.

To find the probability, we divide by the total number of triples, which would be $n^3$, seen also by multiplication principle.  In the example of a $d6$ that would be $6^3=216$.

The correct probability for the six-sided dice example would then be $\frac{90}{216}$ if we are concerned with *exactly* one pair, and would be $\frac{96}{216}$ if we are concerned with *at least* one pear.

---

The term "odds" is related in concept to probability, but technically different.

While the *probability* for exactly one pair in the six-sided dice example is $\frac{90}{216}$ the *odds* will instead be $90~::~126$, in reference to how there are $90$ favorable outcomes versus $126$ unfavorable outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds awfully like a homework question. Please include the homework tag.

If you have three 6 sided dies then the probability of rolling the same number two times is $96/216$. The probability of all the dies having the same value is $6/216$.

Why 216? That is the total amount of possible outcomes from the dies.

Then you can count the amount of times a specific outcome would occur.

For a 12 sided dice it follows the same logic. The probability of all the 3 dies having the same value is $12/1728$. The probability of 2 of them being the same is $408/1728$.

Comment: Why is $66$ the numerator?  Why is $276$?

Comment: I think it's wise to let students do some thinking on their own and do their own homework. This is a hint in the right direction. It's for him to understand the problem.

Comment: Do you think its wise to also give incorrect numbers which might serve to only confuse them further?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.